# Sort Array with Objects to newest date

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I am making an chat App, all Contacts are saved as Objects in one array:

```
var contacts = [{name: "Ruud", age: 20},{name: "Elke", age: 17}];
```

Than I am having the chat messages for every contact saved in an Object Array:

```
var message_ruud = [{mes: "Hi", date: 1477064075},{mes: "Ok", date: 1477066075}];
var message_elke = [{mes: "Lol", date: 1477069075},{mes: "Ok", date: 1477063075}];
```

Now the contacts shell be displayed, sorted by the contact with the highest (so the newest time) timestamp. How to do this (so fast as possible)?

EDIT (because question is not clear):

Finally I want to have an Output of the CONTACTS they shell be sortet to where the newest message was sent, to find out where the newest message is you have the message arrays (like _ruud, _elke).

```js
var contacts = [{name: "Ruud"},{name: "Elke"}];
var message_elke = [{msg: "Hi",date: 20}];
var message_ruud = [{msg: "Hello",date: 10}];

document.getElementById("contacts").innerHTML = contacts[0].name+"</br>"+contacts[1].name;
```

```html
<div id="contacts"></div>
```

It should not displayed in this order but like this: ELKE, RUUD because last message was written to Elke

Comment: you want to sort `message_ruud` and `message_elke` by date - is that what you want?

Comment: yes and thatn output the conatacts array sortet by that

Comment: I did not get that part. Could you please add a sample output to the question?

Comment: no its not a dublicate i am having more arrays

Answer (score 1):

See demo below using [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort `message_ruud` array from lastest to oldest - you can do the same with `message_elke`:

```js
var message_ruud = [{mes: "Hi", date: 1477064075},{mes: "Ok", date: 1477066099}];

var result = message_ruud.sort(function(a,b){
   return (b.date - a.date) || 0;
});

console.log(result);
```

**EDIT**:

Maybe this will point you in the right direction - explanations inline:

```js
var contacts = [{name: "Ruud"},{name: "Elke"}];
var message_elke = [{msg: "Hi",date: 20}, {msg: "Hi",date: 30 }];
var message_ruud = [{msg: "Hello",date: 10}, {msg: "Hello",date: 400}];

var result = contacts.sort(function(a, b) {

  // find max date for Ruud
  var ruud_max = message_ruud.map(function(element) {
    return element.date;
  }).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
  }, 0);

  // find max date for Elke
  var elke_max = message_elke.map(function(element) {
    return element.date;
  }).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
  }, 0);
  
  // sort the contacts array
  return (elke_max - ruud_max) || 0;
});

console.log(result);
```

**EDIT 2**:

Consider the case with many contacts - you need to rethink the data structure. So here goes - looks a bit complicated though! You can test it by extending the data structure for the `message` and the `contact`:

```js
var contacts = [{
  name: "Ruud"
}, {
  name: "Elke"
}, {
  name: "Alan"
}];

var messages = [{
  name: "Ruud",
  message: [{
    msg: "Hello",
    date: 10
  }, {
    msg: "Hello",
    date: 400
  }]
}, {
  name: "Elke",
  message: [{
    msg: "Hi",
    date: 20
  }, {
    msg: "Hi",
    date: 30
  }]
}, {
  name: "Alan",
  message: [{
    msg: "Hi there",
    date: 20
  }, {
    msg: "Lol",
    date: 40
  }]
}];

var result = contacts.sort(function(x, y) {

  var max_date_x = messages.find(function(element){
    return element.name === x.name;     
  }).message.map(function(element) {
    return element.date;
  }).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
  }, 0);

  var max_date_y = messages.find(function(element){
    return element.name === y.name;     
  }).message.map(function(element) {
    return element.date;
  }).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
  }, 0);

  // sort the contacts array
  return (max_date_y - max_date_x) || 0;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: you get it wrong look at my edit

Comment: @TimJansen check out the updated answer - let me know if this solved your query

Comment: yes thats it what I want but how to do this with more contacts? Can you make an example with 3 or 4 Contacts?

Comment: @TimJansen see the new edit - please upvote / accept answer if this answer helped you. :) Thanks!

Comment: sorry, now I had a closer look to your code and saw that you didnt solve the problem. I am having an array for every contact so message_ruud... and so on. You just use one array where all messages are saved in thats wrong. Hope you understood it and hope you can help

Comment: To link the message with the contact array for the general case, as I say in the answer you should ideally have a data structure like so...

Comment: because of other things that is not possible to change it

Comment: If you need a variable for each `message` - in the general case I am not sure how to handle them :(